# How to write logstash multiline for interlaced log lines from different process threads based on a dynamic identifier

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-forwarder, logstash-file

dummy logfile:

```
[1] test123
[2] test234
[3] test345
[2] test321 
[1] test432
[3] test058
[1] test002`
```

expected result from multiline to merge lines with same id and consider as single event.

```
[1] test123
[1] test432
[1] test002
```

Answer (score 0):

The [stream_identity](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-multiline.html#plugins-filters-multiline-stream_identity) property of the multiline filter should work for this.

When using the filter, you can't run more than one worker thread (-w).  The multiline codec is supposed to help with that, but the man page does not describe a stream feature like this.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out !!